# React, put html in jsx inside if-ese

Tags: reactjs, jsx

I want to do this in render:

```
return(
  <NavbarGroup>
    {user.demo ? '<span className="demo-top-title">Demo User</span>' : ''}
  </NavbarGroup>
etc...
```

But I get the same code as text, not as html. I don't know how to use `dangerouslySetInnerHTML` in this situation

Comment: Don't put quotes around html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
return(
  <NavbarGroup>
    {user.demo ? <span className="demo-top-title">Demo User</span> : ''}
  </NavbarGroup>
etc...
```

Use like this.

Comment: Lol, yes. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Just for completeness you can use `&&` short-circuit:

```js
return (
  <NavbarGroup>
    {user.demo && <span className="demo-top-title">Demo User</span>}
  </NavbarGroup>
)
```

Comment: Nice! I saw that around my code, I'll use it now. Thanks.